# What event i need to deal more damage to certain mobs with enchantment?

Tags: java, events, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

```
    @EventHandler
public void onAttack(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event, ItemStack inHand) {       
    if (!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player && !(event.getEntity() instanceof Player))) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        Player player = (Player) event.getDamager();
        if(player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("Orphan Obliterator")) {
            ((Damageable) event).setHealth(0);
    }
    
}
```

**onAttack**

Basically, I need to make an enchantment that deals more damage to certain mobs, like Smite Enchantment. I want to check if the attacker (player) has the enchantment i need on his weapon, if so i need it to deal more damage?
(I did the EnchantmentWrapper and everything)
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your events should only take one argument, change

```
@EventHandler
public void onAttack(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event, ItemStack inHand) {}
```

to

```
@EventHandler
public void onAttack(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {}
```

Also, make sure you're registering your events:

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(Listener, JavaPlugin);
```

where `Listener` is an instance of your class containing your `onAttack` method, and `JavaPlugin` is the instance of your class which `extends JavaPlugin`.